# docker container cannot authenticate with dockerhub to push image built inside of docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image inside of a docker container.

I'm am attempting to use the an authenticated docker daemon on the host machine to push the docker image on dockerhub.

I'm running the docker container with

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock bitcoin-s-build:latest
```

This docker instance on the host machine *is* authenticated correctly with dockerhub. I can run `docker push ...` on the host machine and correctly push an image.

I would like to run the `docker push ...` in the docker container, and use the mounted socket to push the image to dockerhub.

When doing so I get this error:

```
...
#44 exporting manifest list sha256:14472c602ddb92ba1d7c3f8ab0715b807276eaedc16b10230e7f266b2115a3a0 done
#44 pushing layers
#44 pushing layers 0.5s done
#44 ERROR: authorization status: 401: authorization failed

#3 [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest
------
 > exporting to image:
------
error: failed to solve: authorization status: 401: authorization failed
```

To be clear, I *know* the docker daemon on the host machine is properly authenticated.

here is the `Dockerfile` I am using for the build

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:17.0.2_1.6.2_2.13.8

WORKDIR /build

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release

RUN mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings

RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

# https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/
RUN echo \
      "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
      $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin runit-systemd

RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s.git

WORKDIR "/build/bitcoin-s"

ENTRYPOINT ["sbt", "appServer/docker:publish"]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use docker login command for which you want to push image to docker hub or try to use shell program in project and include each commands in shell so that everything will deploy automatically

For example:
shell program will be shell.sh.

docker login.

docker build -t "name".
docker tag name hubuser/name:tag.

docker push hubuser/name:tag.

And in Docker file use CMD ["sh", "shell.sh"].

and run container in interactive mode.
docker run -it -p 0000:0000 --name container imagename.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: The host machine is fully authenticate with docker, the container running on the host machine isn't allowed to push via the socket mounted to the running docker container